Generate random value 0 to 1 using `crypto-js` library
I'm working on a small JS library, it consists of several npm packages for Web, NodeJS and React Native, but all of them use the shared core library.
In the core library I've been using Math.random(), but recently found some nasty randomness issues resulting in a lot of duplicates for certain versions of some React Native engines. I decided to switch to a single source of truth for rng that will be consistent between platforms.
I already use crypto-js for sha256 and it would be amazing if I could utilize crypto-js for switching from Math.random() too.
I checked crypto-js docs and only found CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random to generate random bytes, other things seem to be hashing and cipher related. I'm pretty sure it's possible to transform those bytes to 0-1 random value, but I'm not entirely sure if it could be more reliable than Math.random().
Question: Is there a way to generate reliable random 0 - 1 value similar to Math.random() using crypto-js?

Note that cryptojs is no longer maintained. There's a native Crypto module in Node.

That's right @Pointy , but I won't be able to use modern crypto supporting all platforms

How about … console.log("crypto.getRandomValues() ...", crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 2**32); … this should already improve the "randomness quality" since MDN's crypto.getRandomValues documentation states … "To guarantee enough performance, implementations are not using a truly random number generator, but they are using a pseudo-random number generator seeded [(PRNG)] with a value with enough entropy. The [PRNG] algorithm may vary across user agents, but is suitable for cryptographic purposes."

@PeterSeliger but that's not part of CryptoJS, it's part of the Web Crypto API.

That could be a valid solution @PeterSeliger , the problem is there's no crypto API in React Native, that's why I'm asking specifically about crypto-js

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getBigInt64 - pass the crypto js bytes into the unit[x]array (not sure which would be better here) and follow the instructions to view the integers. to make it 0-1 -> pipe to string, append '0.' in front and remove any non-digit and dot characters with regex -> convert back to number :)

@Slava.In  and Pointy ... oh, I did oversee the react native and CryptoJS library part. I'm sorry for that. One more example of why one should read always carefully to the end.

I don't think there is a shortcut here, and I don't think Crypto-JS will work either. Crypto-JS functions that create "random" bits also need to rely on native platform functions, so that the docs for Ver 4.0.0 of Cryptojs say: In this version Math.random() has been replaced by the random methods of the native crypto module.
For this reason CryptoJS might not run in some JavaScript environments without native crypto module. Such as IE 10 or before or React Native.

I ended up using a dedicated library for React Native due to no Math.random() alternatives available natively
The library is react-native-get-random-values and it uses IOS/Android native implementations for crypto
